# How can I append data in an array from list using native javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am calling data from API and listing the data by name. I want to search and add object by name from the list (**using Add Fav Movie button)** and store the entire data of that object in an array using native javascript.

I can do this in Angularjs , but less idea using native javascript.

```js
function addListItem(title, listId) {
  var ul = document.getElementById(listId);
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.className = 'list-group-item';
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

function afterLoad() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var name = document.createElement('img');
    
    const results = data.results;
     
    // loop through items
    results.forEach(item => {
      addListItem(item.title, "items");
    });
    
    name.src = data.title;
    document.body.appendChild(name);
    }

function afterClick() {
    // changed target to focus search
    var terms = document.getElementById("search").value.split(' ').join('+');
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener('load', afterLoad);
    request.open('GET', 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=8318c431b4fc8a2c4762bf2a52c351ee&query='+terms);
    request.send();

    }

button.addEventListener("click", afterClick);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <title>Get Movies</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb-3">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 id="header-title">Get Movies<span style="display:none">123</span></h1>
  <input style="align:right" type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="search">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Search" id="button">
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="main" class="card card-body">
    <h2 class="title">Add Fav Movies</h2>
    <form class="form-inline mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <h2 class="title">Lists</h2>
    <ul id="items" class="list-group">
      
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

On response JSON I want to select  object of movie *(which I click on list )* under array key `result`. And append that particular movie object on another array. How can I do this ?

Comment: What problem are you facing with the current code?

Comment: @randomSoul not facing problem , I am not getting how to search and pass the object in an array.

Comment: I'am not really clear about what are you trying to achieve. You mean, you want to find the details of movie object entered by the user in `search` (movie name).

Comment: @randomSoul No, I can search the movie and get lists of movies in `<li>` as you can see. Now I want to type the particular movie name from that list on `Add Fav movies` input and when I click add , the object related to that particular movie name must get stored in an array.

Comment: Okay. But your `Lists` is empty.  check your above code.

Comment: @randomSoul First search for a movie on the search bar above you will get lists of movies. Its working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type movie name in  `input` (Favourite movies) and hit the `submit`, check if the input has any value. If it has, then make the array of `textContent` of your favourite movie list and then apply the filter to get movie objects whose name match the user entered value

```js
function addListItem(title, listId) {
  var ul = document.getElementById(listId);
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.className = 'list-group-item';
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

let results;

function afterLoad() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var name = document.createElement('img');
    
    results = data.results;
     
    // loop through items
    results.forEach(item => {
      addListItem(item.title, "items");
    });
    
    name.src = data.title;
    document.body.appendChild(name);
}

function afterClick() {
    // changed target to focus search
    var terms = document.getElementById("search").value.split(' ').join('+');
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener('load', afterLoad);
    request.open('GET', 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=8318c431b4fc8a2c4762bf2a52c351ee&query='+terms);
    request.send();
}

button.addEventListener("click", afterClick);

const submitBtn = document.querySelector('input[value="Submit"]');
const favMovie = document.querySelector('form > input');

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const favMovieName = favMovie.value;
    if(favMovieName.length > 0) {
        const filteredFavMovies = results.filter(({title}) => title.toLowerCase().includes(favMovieName.toLowerCase()));
        console.log(filteredFavMovies);
    }
});
```

```html
<header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb-3">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 id="header-title">Get Movies<span style="display:none">123</span></h1>
        <input style="align:right" type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="search">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Search" id="button">
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div id="main" class="card card-body">
        <h2 class="title">Add Fav Movies</h2>
        <form class="form-inline mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <h2 class="title">Lists</h2>
        <ul id="items" class="list-group">

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly , but I want to pass entire object of of that particular movie not only name. Check what you get in API `result` array in console.

Comment: @NoobCoder - Apply filter directly to the results array, because your favorite list have only movie title. See edit.

Comment: Why it is creating multiple array for each entry.

Comment: @NoobCoder - Because, it is not necessary that the user type exactly movie name, might be he can type few initials or other from movie name. I have used `includes`, so it will check whether user inputted movie name is present in the the `title` property. If you want exact match, then you can remove includes and match using `===` operator, but in this case if the user type partial movie name, then no results would be retrieved.

Comment: Got it thanks , also the array is empty for each entry.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, mark it as accepted so as to indicate that problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.filter to create a new array with only selected items.

```
var filteredItems = allItems.filter(item => {

   if (itesm.year > 1980)
     return true
   else
     return false;

})
```

OR

you can use the Array.forEach method to traverse through the original array and do whatever you want with the items:

```
allItems.forEach(item => {
   if (item.year > 1980)
      addListItem(item.title, "items");

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check by jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/somnath640/emov3yxs/1/

I have removed 2nd form and added ID for both 2nd bottom and input fields. and added another function call against the 2nd button hit.

```js
function addListItem(title, listId) {
  var ul = document.getElementById(listId);
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.className = 'list-group-item';
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

function afterLoad() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var name = document.createElement('img');
    
    const results = data.results;
     
    // loop through items
    results.forEach(item => {
      addListItem(item.title, "items");
    });
    
    name.src = data.title;
    document.body.appendChild(name);
    }

function afterClick() {
    // changed target to focus search
    var terms = document.getElementById("search").value.split(' ').join('+');
    console.log(terms);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.addEventListener('load', afterLoad);
    request.open('GET', 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=8318c431b4fc8a2c4762bf2a52c351ee&query='+terms);
    request.send();

    }
    
    
function addToList(){
 var favMovieName = document.getElementById("fabinput").value;
  addListItem(favMovieName, "items");
  console.log(favMovieName);
}

button.addEventListener("click", afterClick);

addfav.addEventListener("click", addToList);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <title>Get Movies</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb-3">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 id="header-title">Get Movies<span style="display:none">123</span></h1>
  <input style="align:right" type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="search">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Search" id="button">
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="main" class="card card-body">
    <h2 class="title">Add Fav Movies</h2>
    
      <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="fabinput">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" id="addfav" value="Add">

    <h2 class="title">Lists</h2>
    <ul id="items" class="list-group">
      
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your search button is itself adding the first name from the list. The `addFav` button must add. Also I want the entire object of that particular movie in a separate array. Not on the list example :- `[ {object of movie avatar}, {object of movie rambo first blood}]`

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you correct, you want the movies object from themoviedb and append all results to the list `items`?

First you need to replace:

```
    request.addEventListener('load', afterLoad);
```

with:

```
    request.onload = afterLoad;
```

and then need to really define the button.. here is a working example:

```js
function addListItem(title, listId) {
  var ul = document.getElementById(listId);
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.className = 'list-group-item';
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

function afterLoad() {
  var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  var name = document.createElement('img');

  const results = data.results;

  // loop through items
  results.forEach(item => {
    addListItem(item.title, "items");
  });

  name.src = data.title;
  document.body.appendChild(name);
}

function searchMovie() {
  var terms = document.getElementById("search").value.split(' ').join('+');
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onload = afterLoad;
  request.open('GET', 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=8318c431b4fc8a2c4762bf2a52c351ee&query=' + terms);
  request.send();
}

var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener("click", searchMovie);
```

```html
<header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb-3">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 id="header-title">Get Movies<span style="display:none">123</span></h1>
    <input style="align:right" value="Avengers" type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="search">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Search" id="button">
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div id="main" class="card card-body">
    <h2 class="title">Add Fav Movies</h2>
    <form class="form-inline mb-3" action="/" method="POST">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2">
      <input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <h2 class="title">Lists</h2>
    <ul id="items" class="list-group">

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No , I can list from the moviedb based on search but now I want to select a particular movie and add the object data related to selected movie on another array and so on.. it keeps on adding while selecting , just like adding favourites from the list.